# 'Movies' object is not itterable

Tags: python

So, I am learning python using some courses but encountered this error when I tried this :
it give the error that the ***object "Movies" is not itterable in pycharm***,i tried matching it with the code in the videos but to no avail.

```
**index.html:**

<table class="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Genre</th>
      <th>Daily Rate</th>
      <th>Stock</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {% for movie in movies %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ movie.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ movie.genre }}</td>
        <td>{{ movie.daily_rate }}</td>
        <td>{{ movie.number_in_stock }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone



class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
             return self.name


class Movies(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    release_year = models.IntegerField()
    number_in_stock = models.IntegerField()
    daily_rate = models.FloatField()
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
             return self.title
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Movies
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):

    movie = Movies.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'movies/index.html', {'movies': Movies})
```

**The code is supposed to return a html page that shows some categories**, also when i access the webpage, Movies object is shown as 'moviess' with a double s rather than a single one but that unrelated.

Comment: Should that be `{'movies': [movie]}` at the end there? Right now, you pass the class `Movie` which isn't iterable. You had just made a `movie` object, but that's not iterable either. So, a list of `movie` objects?

Comment: thanks, i just figured it out a moment ago.

Answer (score -1):

Found it.

```
def index(request):

    movie = Movies.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'movies/index.html', {'movies': Movies})
```

changed this to :

```
 def index(request):

     movies = Movies.objects.all()
     return render(request, 'movies/index.html', {'movies': movies})
```

Since i figured that Movies isn't itterable so I need to give another object to it.
Found the Variable 'movie' and thought of its funct, them boom!